Run python in exe does not show the terminal
I have a python script that calls APIs and displays the results using print("...")
Using pyinstaller I have created an exe file, this exe file will be used by non-technical colleagues from other departments.
When I run the .exe, no window is opened.
The code runs because I see in the logs that the APIs were called, but there's no interface that shows the print results.
I want to avoid creating an UI with tkinter, I want a simple terminal with progress shown in text.
Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my code :
#functions to call apis here  

def main():
    print("Connecting to API A1... ") 
    result_ev = api_a1()

    if result_ev == 'OK':
        print("Result : ", result_ev) 
    else:
        print("Error please check logs")

    print("------------------------------------------------------------ ") 
     
    print("Connecting to API A2... ") 
    result_pa = api_a2()

    if result_pa == 'OK':
        print("Result : ", result_pa) 
    else:
        print("Error please check logs")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

And then I run this command in Anaconda terminal :
pyinstaller get_data_api.py --onefile --windowed 

Start the executable from the terminal. That's how terminal applications work.

https://superuser.com/a/1462778/105287 not quite the same, but should show the terminal while it runs

Afaik, windowed suppresses 'terminal' outputs
